# Search string from another string in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract information like price,owner,name etc from below string.

```
str='invokeUrl("viewphonenumber","trackCode=Property_for_Rent_View_Phone_BVersion&isPhoto=N&pid=29563627&code=&price=Rs. 29,000&bedroom=2&area=2000 sqft&verified=&possession_status=Immediately&prop_number=1&offer=&owner=Agent&locality=Kadubeesanahalli&city=Bangalore&propertyType=Flat&categoryDesc=Rent&name=Manjunath&brEx=Y&js=true&page=result&from=search&call=N&pageOption=B&isSimilarProperty=N&moisd=50&cardType=card_Rent_O&isNight=true&isNri=false&isVisibleProperty=N<Id=86581&propertyTypeId=10002&cityId=3327&priceNumeric=29000&vph=Y","29563627");createCookie("contactTrackCookieData","Y","10");_gaq.push([ "_trackEvent", "propertySRP", "contactopen","view_card_Rent_O" ]);'
#print(str.split('&'))
```

I want to extract different value from string like price value as Rs. 29,000,owner value as Agent etc.

Could you please help me?

Comment: I am using python 3. I am new to python so am not able to find ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rename the string to `s` instead of `str` as the latter overrides the built-in `str()` function.

So, due to the general nature of this problem, there are many different approaches that you could take. Personally, I would use a `regex` to extract the second `string` inside (which contains the values you want) and then use a mixture of `comprehensions` to form a `dictionary`.

*with `s = your 'str'`:*

```
import re
ss = re.findall('"(.*?)"', s)[1]
d = {p[:p.index('=')]:p[p.index('=')+1:] for p in ss.split('&')}
```

which gives `d` as:

```
{'moisd': '50', 'isNight': 'true', 'owner': 'Agent', 'js': 'true', 'page': 'result', 'isPhoto': 'N', 'trackCode': 'Property_for_Rent_View_Phone_BVersion', 'price': 'Rs. 29,000', 'cardType': 'card_Rent_O', 'isNri': 'false', 'cityId': '3327', 'pid': '29563627', 'pageOption': 'B', 'verified': '', 'bedroom': '2', 'offer': '', 'priceNumeric': '29000', 'city': 'Bangalore', 'prop_number': '1', 'categoryDesc': 'Rent', 'possession_status': 'Immediately', 'propertyType': 'Flat', 'from': 'search', 'isVisibleProperty': 'N<Id=86581', 'locality': 'Kadubeesanahalli', 'call': 'N', 'isSimilarProperty': 'N', 'area': '2000 sqft', 'code': '', 'vph': 'Y', 'brEx': 'Y', 'name': 'Manjunath', 'propertyTypeId': '10002'}
```

If the above needs explaining, just let me know!

---

So you could then do something like the following to extract your `price` value:

```
>>> d['price']
'Rs. 29,000'
```